# MongoDB replica set - virtual IP , downtime questions

Tags: mongodb

I have 3 questions regarding a replica set on mongodb on windows:

1. I currently have a standalone running with data on it, if I create a replica set (adding 2 secondries) will I have a downtime or I can create the replica set and adding 2 secondries while the standalone (now the primary) still running?
2. Will the 2 secondries copy all the data from the primary? Also data that was written to standalone before it became part of replica set?
3. Once there is an election a secondry become a primary but then it means the primary is on differnt IP + Port, this means I also need to change my write to the new primary by myself or mongodb doing it by himself? or need to use virtual ip?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a look at [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/).
   You need to change the configuration file and restart the MongoDB, so you have a downtime of your MongoDB.
2. Yes, whenever you add a new member to a replica set then MonogDB performs a [Initial Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-sync/#replica-set-initial-sync) to the new secondary
3. You would need to change your connection, see [Connect to a MongoDB Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/#connect-to-a-mongodb-replica-set). The connection string contains all replica set members and the client will connect (by default) to the primary.

Actually you don't have to put all replica set members in your connection string, the client will discover them automatically. However, if you put only one member and by chance this member is down then you have no connection.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and great answers, just to make sure: so the downtime i'll experience is only to turn off the mongod and start a new one running as a replica set with the new conf file right? Also what's the best way to backup the whole standalone before proceeding such procedure? just to make sure nothing will go wrong

Comment: Downtime will be mongod restart plus `rs.initiate()` I guess.

Comment: For backup either run an export with `mongodump` or `mongoexport` of your collections. Or run `db.fsyncLock()` - this does not stop the database but it locks it, i.e. it prevents any write operation to the DB. Then you can take a copy/snapshot of entire `dbPath` folder. Run `db.fsyncUnlock()` afterwards to unlock the database.